# How to return all id's per day in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table CLIENT(id, name, date). in mssql. how can i return all the id's per day. say for instance I have a poller and i want to insert script into a poller that polls once a day. what script will return all the id's created today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `date` is a date with no time component, the simplest way to get the records on the current date is:

```
select id
from client
where date = cast(getdate() as date);
```

If there is a time component, then use:

```
where date >= cast(getdate() as date) and date < cast(getdate() + 1 as date)
```

Notice that the functions (`cast()`) are not on the columns but on `getdate()`.  This allows the query optimizer to use an index on `date`, if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

use DATEDIFF function to get the difference between datetime in db vs current date

```
SELECT ID FROM Client WHERE DATEDIFF(day, Date, GETDATE()) = 0;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, will this return all the id's for the last 24 hours(per day)

Comment: This is correct, but inefficient because the predicate is not [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT id
FROM CLIENT
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Not the expected answer. Return data for specific date

Comment: But your query just sort the IDs. You are comparing wrong answer with wrong answer.